# c++, Qt How to load a file and save loaded files as QObject in a list

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qfiledialog

This is my first question.

I want to load files like *.txt files and store these files as QObject (is it even possible to save these files as QObject?) in a list for a later use.

Like i open 3 *.txt files and store them as QObject in a list and want to edit these files by calling them from the list

How can i open a file in qt and store this loaded file as QObject in a list?

Could you please provide an example?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You will have to declare a subclass of `QObject` and implement the required functionality. How exactly you do that is entirely up to you. There is no single universal rule everyone is required to follow for storing content in a `QObject`, each application implements it in a way that's the most convenient for that application. `QObject` is just a generic superclass that provides shared functionality for various classes that derive from it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sam. How do i load files? (with which method?) And how can i use these loaded files?(with which method?)

Comment: To be honest, this question sounds like "I don't know how to program with Qt, please write my code for me".

Answer (score 0):

The method to load files in Qt has been completely explained in Qt Documentations of QFile:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html

specially for txt files they provided a code snippet which works perfect with many situations :

```
    QFile file("in.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;

QTextStream in(&file);
while (!in.atEnd()) {
    QString line = in.readLine();
    process_line(line);
}
```

I don't know if you really want to save files as QObject as Sam has mentioned (so you should subclass it and implement your own functions) or you just want a simple `QList<QFile>` list so you can access to your loaded files easily after.
tell me if you needed an example for this ;-)

Comment: Hey tyank for you answer and the example. Yes an example  of QList<QFile> would be great too.